# How to enable logging for gRPC in .NET Core 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, grpc, .net-core-3.0, asp.net-core-3.0

I have an ASP.NET Core 3.0 (3.0.0-preview8-28405-07) server application which is using gRPC (0.1.22) with protocol buffers. I'd like to enable logging to a file or console.

Below is an example of a .Startup file:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddGrpc(options =>
        {
            options.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
        });
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapGrpcService<GreeterService>();
        });
    }
}
```

And the GreeterService:

```
public class GreeterService : Greeter.GreeterBase
{
    public override Task<HelloReply> SayHello(HelloRequest request, ServerCallContext context)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(new HelloReply
        {
            Message = "Hello " + request.Name
        });
    }
}
```

gRPC has a logging class called Grpc.Core.Logging.ILogger. How can I set this up so it is logging to a file or console?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Logging with GRPC in ASP.NET core 3 is handled the same way for any other [ASP.NET app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.0).

You can enable logging by running

```
hostBuilder.ConfigureLogging(logging =>
        {
            logging.AddConsole();
        })
```

in your `program.cs` entry point file or by running

```
serviceCollection.AddLogging(logging =>
            {
                logging.AddConsole();
            });
```

in your `ConfigureServices` method in `startup.cs`